# Font affects MS Word's spell check ability?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, spell-check

When I use the Wingdings font, the spell checker doesn't work (Wingdings isn't the only font I have this problem, there are others).

How can I fix this, how can I force the spell checker to ignore the font, and focus on the characters themselves?

This is what I mean:
[image: My document]

BTW  I did **not** click ignore, or anything of that nature.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you want to spell check non-English characters as English? Your best bet would be to convert the dingbat font to a generic font like `Times New Roman`, spell check, and then change it back to `Wingdings`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd assume this is because different fonts could signify different languages. English fonts are checked using the appropriate English spelling dictionary, but for non-English fonts it would not make sense to check it using an English dictionary. Wingdings being a symbol font, not a language font, is probably not checked by any dictionary ever.

Another way to look at it is this: If you were typing in a font such as MSP Mincho (Japanese), you would not want the system to spell check the output based on an English dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure? Modern computers don't do symbol substitution for fonts and instead use character sets such as Unicode in which the character presented has no direct connection with the glyph. For example C and С are different characters no matter which font you use. Same thing with M and М. Also try opening  miсrosoft.com

Comment: Also English spellchecking works fine with Japanese fonts that ship with windows.